# Не срабатывает присваивание переменной через setState в react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, setstate

Пишу простенькую форму лог ина и регистрации. У меня имеется компонент с формой, в которую я ввожу телефон. В `componentDidMound` я выполняю `fetch` запрос для получения json с моего сервера. Далее я записываю в переменную `input_phone` номер телефона, который я ввёл в форме. Затем я сравниваю `input_phone` с полями `phone` в моём json. Если совпадения имеются - записываю в переменную `isRegistered` true, иначе - вывожу сообщение, что совпадений нет. Однако проблема в том, что при попытке задать состояние с помощью `setState`, у меня ничего не выходит, потому что в консоли выводит false, однако при повторной попытке нажатия уже выведет true. Так же если нажать Sign in при пустом поле. Он всё время будет выводить false, но если ввести совпадающее значение, то он выведет опять же только со второй попытки true.

Вот и не могу понять, почему так выходит. Есть чувство, что я неправильно использую состояния, но в таком случае может ли кто-нибудь подсказать, как правильно это сделать?

```
  class AuthLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      users: [],
      input_phone:''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignin = this.handleSignin.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/users")
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( data => {
          this.setState({
            users: data,
            isRegistered: false
          });

        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            error
          });
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
}

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      input_phone: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSignin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { users, isRegistered } = this.state;
    users.map( user => (
      parseInt(this.state.input_phone) === parseInt(user.phone) ? this.setState({isRegistered: true}) : console.log("No matches"),
      console.log(`is matches: ${isRegistered}, phone: ${user.phone}`)
    ))
    if (isRegistered) {
        console.log("User is already registered");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div className = "loginForm">
            <h1 align = "center"> Пожалуйста, войдите </h1>
              <form id="formLog">
                <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="PHONE" onChange = {this.handleChange} required></input>
                <input id="submit_log" type="submit" value="Sign in" onClick = {this.handleSignin}></input>
                <Link to = "AuthRegister"><input id="signup" type="button" value="Sign up" ></input></Link>
              </form>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: а почему вы хотите впихнуть ошибку в state ?? я вот это не понимаю.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов почему ошибку? А конкретней?

Comment: вот тут __(error) => {this.setState({error});__

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, а. Это код, переработанный из документации. Позже я хотел сделать для него более красивый рендер, поэтому он пока что такой. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

все верно `setState` является асинхронной функцией, поэтому в функции `handleSignin` вы и видите `false`.

У функции `setState` есть `callback`

```
this.setState({
    isRegistered: true
}, () => {
    // в этом месте можете вывести this.state.isRegistered
    // и это значение будет такое, какое вы ожидаете
})
```

P.S: как только у вас `isRegistered === true`, в `false` оно никогда не превратится. Я бы посоветовал переписать вот так (в вашей функции `handleSignin`):

```
this.setState({
    isRegistered: parseInt(this.state.input_phone) === parseInt(user.phone)
})
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, прошу прощения за столь долгое отсутствие. Благодарен за то, что подсказали о том, что есть колбэк. Однако проблема всё равно актуальная, потому что в колбэке я получаю всё то же значение isRegistered =  false, когда при этом в строке перед я вывожу console.log(parseInt(this.state.input_phone) === parseInt(user.phone)) и получаю true. Таким образом, я понимаю, что где-то опять же упускаю особенность setState, которая не даёт мне присвоить isRegistered: true